# Colas, Nodos, Comparación de nodos java Cola con prioridad

Tags: java, diseño-de-clases

eso es lo que tengo https://mega.nz/#!BdRQiLoD!B2tayn1_2oUUi4iB9Gv0OvjRvuFMMa3j46_lqqL4GKk

tengo un problema

estoy haciendo una proyecto en java application, el cual consiste en lo siguiente: pedir datos en una cola y después extraerlos según el numero mayor de años,(por ejemplo: se pide nombre y edad, y extraerlos de la cola según el que sea mayor)

tengo los datos como..

(String nombre)

(int edad)

(String pais(distancia ))

estos datos los pido y los encolo.

lo que quiero saber es como hacer para que salga el que tenga mayor edad y distancia

ejemplo

(Fulano de 32 años de mexico(entra)),

(Mengano de 62 años de brasil(entra)),

(Solano de 43 años de peru(entra))

y que se imprima así:

primero:  Mengano de 62 años de brasil

segundo: Solano de 43 años de peru

tercero: Fulano de 32 años de mexico

Comment: Podias añadir algo de código que hayas intentado. Ayudanos a ayudarte, no estamos para hacerte los deberes.

Comment: ¿Te están pidiendo que codifiques una cola de prioridad?

Comment: Está pidiendo que le hagan las tareas...

Comment: Hola!!
No estoy pidiendo que me hagan la tarea, estoy pidiendo ayuda, ya tengo el proyecto, y ya compila....ya deje el enlace para que lo descarguen y lo vean por si mismo....ojala me puedan ayudar...

quisiera un consejo o un ejemplo de un metodo para desencolar una cola segun el año o distancia...

Answer (score 1):

No te voy a hacer el codigo, pero tratare de darte una mano con tu problema.

Me imagino que si ya agarraste estructuras abstractas de datos con nodos, no hace falta que te explique el proceso de encolar o desencolar un dato. Partamos de que eso ya lo sabes hacer.

Entonces cuando yo desencolo un dato (sin condicion alguna ni por edad ni por nombre) despues de desencolarlo ya lo perdi.Entonces tengo 2 formas de no perder el dato desencolado:

1. Utilizar una cola auxiliar, donde voy a guardar los nodos desencolados, para despues restaurar los datos. (pasar nodos de auxiliar a la original cola).
2. Desencolar dato (hacer con ese dato lo que debo hacer) y despues volver a encolarlo en la misma cola. Aca tenemos un problema, si yo lo desencolo desde el principio y se encola al final, mi ciclo de lectura nunca terminara. En este caso existe un concepto llamado **centinela**.

> Centinela: es un dato distinto (logicamente) a todos los otros datos
>   de la cola.

Ejemplo: Tengo cola las edades de personas.

```
cola: 18 - 19 - 60 - 35 - 45 - 22 - 70 - 999
```

Como ya te diste cuenta **999** es el centinela.(no puede haber una edad asi)

Entonces tomando el 2do caso, vamos a ver el algoritmo de como desencolar edades segun algun criterio, utilizando centinela.

- Tengo que sacar de la cola personas mayores a 55 años.

La cola original es esta: `18 - 60 - 35 - 45 - 22 - 70`

1. Primero encolo el centinela:

   18 - 60 - 35 - 45 - 22 - 70 - 999
2. Empiezo el ciclo `WHILE` con la condicion (mientras el dato del nodo desencolado sea distinto del **999**, o sea distinto del centinela. Para saber que ya hice la vuelta entera).
3. Desencolo el primer dato y pregunto (18 > 55). Me da **no** y lo encolo de vuelta.

Estado de la cola:  `60 - 35 - 45 - 22 - 70 - 999 - 18`

4. Desencolo el proximo dato y pregunto (60 > 55). Me da **si**, entonces no lo encolo, o lo paso a otro cola, como vos quieras.

Estado de la cola: `35 - 45 - 22 - 70 - 999 - 18`

5. Los pasos se repiten dentro del ciclo `WHILE` hasta que desencola **999**.
   Como la condicion de ese ciclo era (dato != centinela) da **FALSE**

Cuando se va, ya se va con ese centinela desencolado, por ende ese nodo se pierde y la cola original deberia quedar asi:

```
18 - 35 - 45 - 22
```

Fijate que la cola conservo el orden original de los datos, solo que no estan las edades mayores a 55 años.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias por ese dato importante, lo tomare en cuenta ;-)